# Webscraping: Data Frame not filling

Tags: r, web-scraping

So I'm looking to scrape data from [TransferMarkt](http://www.transfermarkt.com/), specifically the name and URLs of players in the premier league. I'm doing this by first scraping the URLs of all the teams in the league, then going through the individual players in those teams. Problem I'm having is that the data isn't saving into the frame. When I'm trying to find the number of rows (no.of.rows), it is still at zero, so I tried to print the frame (Catcher1) to see what what's happening, and it's empty! Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "http://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1"

WS <- read_html(URL)

URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes(".hide-for-pad .vereinprofil_tooltip") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character()
URLs <- paste0("http://www.transfermarkt.com",URLs)

Catcher1 <- data.frame(Player=character(),P_URL=character())

for (i in URLs) {
  WS1 <- read_html(i)
  Player <- WS1 %>% html_nodes("#yw1 .tooltipstered")%>%html_text()%>%as.character()
  P_URL <- WS1 %>% html_nodes("#yw1 .tooltipstered")%>%html_attr("href")%>%as.character()
  temp <- data.frame(Player,P_URL)
  Catcher1 <- rbind(Catcher1,temp)
  cat("*")
}

print(Catcher1)
no.of.rows <- nrow(Catcher1)
odd_indexes<-seq(1,no.of.rows,2)
Catcher1 <- data.frame(Catcher1[odd_indexes,])

Catcher1$P_URL <- paste0("http://www.transfermarkt.com",Catcher1$P_URL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a `#yw1` id but this has a specific enough CSS selector to get what you want (though I rly don't know as I don't engage in this type of sports scraping nor follow this sport).

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

URL <- "http://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1"

WS <- read_html(URL)

html_nodes(WS, ".hide-for-pad .vereinprofil_tooltip") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  sprintf("http://www.transfermarkt.com%s", .) -> URLs

pb <- progress_estimated(length(URLs))
map_df(URLs, ~{

  pb$tick()$print()

   Sys.sleep(sample(3:6, 1)) # be kind to the remote site since you're using a robot vs a human and you have time

  tmp <- read_html(.x)

  data_frame(
    player = html_nodes(tmp, "td > div:first-of-type > span > a.spielprofil_tooltip") %>% html_text(),
    url = html_nodes(tmp, "td > div:first-of-type > span > a.spielprofil_tooltip") %>% html_attr("href")
  )

}) -> players_df

players_df
## # A tibble: 571 x 2
##              player                                     url
##               <chr>                                   <chr>
##  1 Thibaut Courtois /thibaut-courtois/profil/spieler/108390
##  2    Asmir Begovic     /asmir-begovic/profil/spieler/33873
##  3          Eduardo           /eduardo/profil/spieler/34159
##  4   Jamal Blackman   /jamal-blackman/profil/spieler/128898
##  5       David Luiz        /david-luiz/profil/spieler/46741
##  6      Gary Cahill       /gary-cahill/profil/spieler/27511
##  7       Kurt Zouma       /kurt-zouma/profil/spieler/157509
##  8       Nathan Aké       /nathan-ake/profil/spieler/177476
##  9      Tomás Kalas      /tomas-kalas/profil/spieler/148657
## 10       John Terry         /john-terry/profil/spieler/3160
## # ... with 561 more rows
```

Comment: if it works, it helps others to tick the answered box so they know it's a working answer